# MySQL REPLACE unicode characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, replace

I'm trying to replace a Unicode character with another one.

I'm running this but it's not working.

```
UPDATE items SET `data` = REPLACE(`data`, '\u030C', '\u0306');
```

I've tried `REPLACE` without the `\` or `\u` and also with multiple slashes like `\\\\\\\\\\\\u030C`. I've pretty much run out of random combinations to try to make this work.

How can I get this replace working.

Comment: What client are you using?  (PHP will probably need more backslashes than the mysql commandline tool.)

Comment: I'm just trying to make it work in mysql for now. It's not even working there.

Answer (score 1):

Can we back up a step and avoid getting the `\u` encoding?  If you are using PHP:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**Addenda**

In mysql commandline tool, use 2 backslashes:

```
UPDATE items SET `data` = REPLACE(`data`, '\\u030C', '\\u0306');
```

Are you replacing a combining caron with a combining breve?

Don't you really want the utf8 character instead of the unicode code?

Comment: Yes, that is a good option. But I also have an existing table full of these.

Comment: Worked for me. But it was difficult to know I need to use 2 backslashes. They say inside replace you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: @Hebe - The number of backslashes (1 vs 2 vs 4) depends on the number of layers of programs you have to go through.  I experiment on something harmless in order to discover how many to use.  Turn the UPDATE into a SELECT so you can see what is happening (somewhat),  Use HEX() or LENGTH() or CHAR_LENGTH() to get more insight into whether it was replaced correctly.